# Python3 Let threads finish when keyboardexception raised

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I'm looking for a way to let the threads finish their work and not take a new job if CTRL-C is raised. 
Theorical code:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue(maxsize=0)
def work(q):
    print (line)
for line in file_of_100_line:
    q.put(line)
nbThreads = 2
for i in range(nbThreads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(q))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Let the workers print the line if keyboard exception is raised (CTRL-C), and when all workers are done with their current task, quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
import signal
import threading
from time import sleep

keep_running = True

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global keep_running
    keep_running = False
    print("Received SIGINT\n")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal_handler)

def work():
    while keep_running:
        sleep(2)
    print("Worker finished\n")

nbThreads = 2
threads = []
for i in range(nbThreads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=work)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

while any([t.isAlive() for t in threads]):
    sleep(0.1)
```

Letting this program run yields

```
Received SIGINT

Worker finished
Worker finished
```

Explanation: When CTRL-C is pressed the program receives a `signal.SIGINT` which causes the registered handler `signal_handler` to be called setting the global variable `keep_running` to `False`. Meanwhile the main thread waits for all spawned threads to die. Thus these threads can finish whatever they were doing (in this case `sleep`-ing) before the main thread terminates.

Note: On Linux waiting for a signal could be achieved by calling `signal.pause()` (replacing the `sleep(0.1)`). On Windows this is not possible because this function does not exist. Therefore the above should be less platform-dependant.

Comment: All I have to do in order to still print the "worker finished" while it runs, is to replace the last line with "continue", right?

Comment: What should be replaced instead to keep the workers print "worker finished" and when ctrl+C is hit, to let them finish.. and exit?

Comment: Because I would like the function work() to run even before ctrl+C is hit.

Comment: I really read that wrong...Got it, last thing, you said replacing sleep by continue will waste cpu cycle, but sleep(0.1) won't? Should I give more time to the sleep function? E.G: sleep(2)

Comment: It depends on how *responsive* you want the program to be. After all threads are done the Program can take up to the amount of time the body of the last while loop takes to actually finish. So sleeping longer is more *efficient*, but the program might seem unresponsive. Therefore I think sleeping for 1/10 of a second is a good tradeoff.